# como solucionar Sol con el [Error] assignment of function 'float promedio(int*, int)'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

necesito ayuda me ese error y no como se cambiarlo, soy nuevo en esos en la programación y este error la verdad no se como solucionarlo y no lo entiendo estuve viendo algunas preguntas similares pero no llegue a entenderlo, intente cambiar los valores pero nada, además si o si necesito sacar la cantidad de alumnos aprobados o si no puedo completar la consigna que me han dado del cursillo.

Consigna:
Primero, tenés que ingresar 25 notas y las podés cargar en un vector, después te fijaste el valor de cada nota que sea enteré 0-10, con un if por ejemplo.
El promedio es la suma de todas las notas en este caso dividido 25,son 25 alumnos, y al mismo tiempo podés ir sumando en un contador, la cantidad de alumnos que sacaron menos de siete.

gracias de antemano

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float promedio(int valores[], int cantidad) {
    int i;
    float suma = 0.0;
 
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i)
        suma += valores[i];
 
    return suma / (float) cantidad;
}
 
 
int main() {

    float  Contador=1; 
    float ContA=0; 
    float ContR=0;
    int notas[10];
    char nombre[20];
    char opcion[3];
    int n, i;
 
    do {
        printf("Ingrese nombre del alumno: ");
        scanf("%s", nombre);
 
        printf("Cuantas notas tiene %s? ", nombre);
        scanf("%d", &n);
 
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("  Nota %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
        }
 
        printf("El promedio de %s es %.1f\n", nombre, promedio(notas, n));
 
        printf("Desea calcular mas promedios (si/no)? ");
        scanf("%s", opcion);
     

 
    } while (opcion[0] == 's' || opcion[0] == 'S');
           while(Contador=Contador+1)
    {


 
        if(promedio=3;)
            ContA++;
 
        if(promedio < 3);
            ContR++;
 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Hola Joel, en el ultimo bucle:

```cpp
while(Contador = Contador+1)
{ 
         if(promedio == 3)
             ContA++;
     
         if(promedio < 3)
             ContR++;     
}
```

En la comparación que se hace a la entrada del bucle while, no estas haciendo una comparación realmente, sino un incremento. De esta manera entra en el bucle incrementando la variable contador hasta que llega a su valor máximo permitido (después de muchas iteraciones innecesarias).
Para hacer una comparación habría que poner == entre los dos términos a comparar.
De la misma manera, en el condicional `if(promedio=3)`, también haces una asignación, pero esta vez de una función sin argumentos, por lo tanto un puntero. La manera correcta seria `if(promedio(notas,n)==3)`.
De todos modos, según el enunciado lo que te interesa es obtener el numero de alumnos que han obtenido un promedio menor a 7. Por tanto solo nos hace falta una variable int para guardar este numero. Cada vez que el promedio sea menor se incrementa esta variable dentro del primer bucle. Luego se imprime por pantalla al salir.
Con estos pequeños matices, el código seria así:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float promedio(int valores[], int cantidad) {
    int i;
    float suma = 0.0;
 
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i)
        suma += valores[i];
 
    return suma / (float) cantidad;
}
int main()
{

    float Contador = 1;
    float ContA = 0;
    float ContR = 0;
    int notas[10];
    char nombre[20];
    char opcion[3];
    int n, i; 
    do
    {
        printf("Ingrese nombre del alumno: ");
        scanf("%s", nombre);

        printf("Cuantas notas tiene %s? ", nombre);
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            printf("  Nota %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
        }

        printf("El promedio de %s es %.1f\n", nombre, promedio(notas, n));

        printf("Desea calcular mas promedios (si/no)? ");
        scanf("%s", opcion);
        if (promedio(notas, n) < 7) ContR ++;
    } while (opcion[0] == 's' || opcion[0] == 'S');

    printf("el numero de alumnos con promedio menor de siete es de %d \n", ContR );
     
    return 0;
}
```

Saludos Joel, espero haberte sido de ayuda. Si tienes cualquier duda me dices, no te preocupes.

Comment: Realmente el bucle no es indefinido ... termina cuando `Contador==0` aunque claro, siendo un `int` eso sucederá después de 2^32 iteraciones

Comment: ¿No daría sobrecarga al llegar al limite?

Comment: ¿qué es eso? En c++ no hay chequeo de desbordamientos, si es a lo que te refieres. Cuando haces una operación cuyo resultado no _entra_ en la variable, lo que sobra se pierde y tan ricamente. Es tu responsabilidad evitar que eso pase

Comment: Si, me refería a desbordamiento, perdón. De todos modos no se ve la necesidad de ese bucle

Comment: en eso estamos de acuerdo, solo te lo puntualizaba para que pudieses afinar la respuesta